# PHP session not registering when opening page from a Word document

Tags: php, session, authentication, ms-word

I'm stumped on this one. I have a members only page which when a user is not logged in will force the user to log in (redirect to login page). The target URL ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) is  stored in a session and when the user successfully logs in, he/she is directed to that target page. This works fine and dandy in the browser.

However, when I have a link in a Word document to a members only page and click it to open it in the browser, the session variable fails to register. Am I missing a setting somewhere that would cause such an issue?

This is the authentication code here.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if((!isset($_SESSION['uid']))||($_SESSION['uid']=='')){ 
        $_SESSION['targetURL']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header( 'Location: /login.php' ) ;  
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Again, that works fine when navigating within browser, or typing the URL in directly in the address bar... But any links from Word don't allow the session to be registered.

Comment: There is no reason why a link from a word processor should cause issues like this. I would recommend dumping $_SESSION and $_SERVER with print_r() at the start of your script, to see what is going on.

Comment: Oh yes, do check that session cookies are enabled in the browser ;-)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'll try the dump. The cookies are enabled :).  If i convert that same word doc to pdf and click on that link, it works fine!! I guess MS is out to get me... again...

Comment: Hmm, could Word be launching a new instance of IE every time you click a link? I am not familiar with it tbh - Open Office all the way for me :). If IE is your default browser, try changing it to something else to see if that has any effect.

Comment: i've tried firefox/ie/chrome.. all same issues. The dump didn't help much. it just returned an empty array for the sessions.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old post, but I just ran across the same problem. Microsoft has a knowledge base article that explains this behavior...

> This behavior occurs because the Office session is independent of the Web browser session in which you may have already provided user credentials.

and

> If the SSO system exclusively relies on session cookie information, the SSO system may not appear to work because the same user moves from more than one session.

The post goes on to say that this is by design and is a limitation of the SSO system, not a limitation of Microsoft Word. At the bottom of the article are a number of solutions to "fix" your system, although the article admits that they add significant complexity. If you truly need links to work from a Word document, you'll have to implement one of the suggested solutions.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899927

However, as a quick workaround, if you don't have to use a Word Document, you can convert your document to a PDF, which doesn't suffer from the same problem.